# python method for defining indexing in a class (use of "[ ]")

Tags: python, class, indexing, methods

I understand that `__add__` can be used to define the use of `+` for a new class. What is the equivalent for defining the use of `[]`?

I would like to create a class `Parent` that contains a dictionary `codes`, and I would like `Parent[key]` to return `Parent.codes[key]`

I understand that I could probably just use `Parent.codes[key]`, but this seems needlessly verbose if methods can be used to avoid similar issues with things like `+` and `==`.

Comment: `__getitem__`. Also `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` if you need that.

Comment: The complete list (other than library-specific ones) is at: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: @o11c. But that's what inheritance is really for.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sort of. It is almost always the case that composition is both more flexible and intuitive than inheritance. The requirements on inheritance are pretty strict: and it's difficult to tell with this limited information that it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Matt. While generally true, I've found Python inheritance to be much more flexible and less restrictive than most other languages I'm familiar with. The lack of true privacy leans me in favor of inheritance as well, since you can't hide any part of the API anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options. If you what your class to quack like a `dict`, your best The best bet is probably just to extend `dict` instead of referencing one and attempting to redirect all the methods:

```
class Parent(dict):
    # probably do something with the constructor, maybe
```

This will allow you to index right into `Parent`, list the keys, iterate over the values, etc. At the same time, you can add whatever additional attributes, properties and methods your heart desires.

The literal answer to your question is [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) and [`__delitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__). You can implement the three use-cases of the indexing operator with these methods:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.codes = dict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
         return self.codes[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
         self.codes[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
         del self.codes[key]
```

The methods are invoked on an instance of `Parent` in exactly the same way that `Parent` redirects them to `dict`.

For future reference, the methods shown here (including your example of `__add__`) are called magic, special or dunder methods. All dunder (double underscore) attributes are reserved by the interpreter. They serve many purposes, including operator overloading in custom objects. The (nearly) complete spec of existing names is available in the documentation of the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
```

edit:

more specifically, what you want is:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
   return self.Codes[key]
```

edit2: delete some irrelevant text on `__iter__` and `__next__` (see comments)

Comment: Do not call `__iter__` yourself, instead, use `yield from Codes`. As for `__next__`, op is not implementing an iterator and a `__dict__` does not have a `__next__` method.

Comment: @Olivier. Or better yet, just `return iter(codes)`.

Comment: Thanks, I removed those parts from the text